# Верификация данных пользователя

Tags: php, moodle

Друзья, где можно посмотреть готовый пример подобного. При авторизации форма для ввода актуальных данных, например почта и телефон, после, подверждения пустит на сайт.

На PHP 
Нужно в частности для moodle

Comment: Не при регистрации, а такая страничка верификации которая не пускает никуда пока не подтвердишь для уже зарегестрированных пользователей

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто создай в БД еще два столбца - verify и token
При регистрации генирируй различные символы и отправь e-mail с сылкой типа site.ru/?token={только что созданный токен}
На главной странице поставь проверку

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['token'])){$token=$_GET['token'];
//Потом соеденись с бд и обнови столбец verify на true 
}
?>
```

Comment: Не при регистрации, а такая страничка верификации которая не пускает никуда пока не подтвердишь для уже зарегестрированных пользователей